# How to use like pivote result in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
 Insert into @temp3
 select 
 Distinct t.staffName,
    attendDate = convert(date,t.AttendDate)

  , t.staffId
  , t.Firmid
  ,t.ShiftName
  , t.attendId
  , CheckIn  = convert(time(0),t.AttendDate)
  , CheckOut = convert(time(0),x.AttendDate)
from @temp2 as t
outer  apply (
  select top 1 i.AttendDate
  from @temp2  as i
  where t.staffid = i.staffid
    and i.attendDate > t.attendDate
  order by i.attendDate desc
) x
where t.InOutMode = 'CheckIn'
```

[image: How to get First CheckIn and Last Check Out Value?]

[[image: I want to display checkIn and CheckOut as a column]
Please Check First Image I want to get first CheckIn and Last Check Out

I have below Result I want to show checkIn and checkOut as Column 
Like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
atteDate  | staffName      |  staffId | Firmid |attendId | CheckIn |CheckOut |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-11-13|Urvashi A Patel |7023     |6012 | 204 | 9:30:03 | 18:34:17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an aggregation query, grouping by the date of `attendDate`.

```
select 
    attendDate = convert(date,t.AttendDate)
  , t.staffName
  , t.staffId
  , t.Firmid
  , attendId   = min(t.attendId)
  , CheckIn    = min(convert(time(0),t.AttendDate))
  , CheckOut   = max(convert(time(0),t.AttendDate))
from t
group by 
    t.staffName
  , t.staffId
  , t.Firmid
  , convert(date,t.attendDate)
```

---

If you are getting an error because you are trying to use this with some query that gives you the results above, it would be best to include that query in your question.

If that is the case, then using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) might help.

```
;with cte as (
/* query that does stuff to get the results in your question */
)

select 
    attendDate = convert(date,t.AttendDate)
  , t.staffName
  , t.staffId
  , t.Firmid
  , attendId   = min(t.attendId)
  , CheckIn    = min(convert(time(0),t.AttendDate))
  , CheckOut   = max(convert(time(0),t.AttendDate))
from t
group by 
    t.staffName
  , t.staffId
  , t.Firmid
  , convert(date,t.attendDate)
```

Comment: Dude... why on earth would you say that and _not_ post the error? Are we mind readers?

Comment: I got answer and my error also gone. but I want to show each day check In and Check Out If There is no check Out value then this cell will be display empty

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: Can You help me

Comment: @MaheshGawhane switch to `outer apply()` instead of `cross apply()`

Comment: This and is correct Only my Problem is I want to get First Check in and last Check out . You can see in First image .

Comment: @SqlZim Can you help me?

Comment: @SqlZim actually Outer apply() is work for me but there is smaller issue . suppose my checkout time is null it will take automatically next day checkin time .

Comment: @MaheshGawhane That's a different question, post it as a new question with sample data and desired results.